# What does the "f" symbol mean in the Android Studio debugger?

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, member

## Background

In the Android debugger, an "f" inside a yellow circle appears next to the traits of an object:

[image]

Most of these seem to begin with an m, which lead me to believe they are [members](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/reflect/Member).  But they have an f symbol next to them that seems indicative of something else.

## Question

What does the "f" mean in an Android debugger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [JetBrains documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/symbols.html). There are the names for those icons but unfortunatly they did not add a whole description to it so I'm also a little bit confused over the term "Field" the "f" is refering to.